# Getting a error while make components in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm facing an error. When ever I make a new component and try to open it in localhost, it doesn't show it.

I made few components both manually by using commands but it doesn't work.

The error which i m getting is that app.component is not a module.

Here is the code.

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { RecipeDetailsComponent } from './recipes/recipe-details/recipe-details.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.component.ts` :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes></app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list></app-shopping-list>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: we dont have the complete code but for me it seems that you are missing the declaration import for the `app-shopping-list` component

Comment: would be great if you can build a stackblitz with a minimal reproducable example of your structure and code

Comment: Hi. Can you share the exact error you're getting and also show how you're creating your components? Also, remember to save the files you've created and restart your server. As @DerHerrGammler has already suggested: `build a stackblitz with a minimal reproducable example of your structure and code`

Comment: Hey, The exact error is that which i try to run the components which i have created are not working. i add the component in html code but it somehow doesn't work.